# Convert SVG to PNG programmatically

Tags: svg, vb6

Is there a way to programmatically convert a SVG string in a PNG file using VB6 code without using inskape or others command line tools?

EDIT: Some details, this conversion could be performed in the IE web browser control but all examples with canvas works perfectly with firefox or chrome but not in IE (9-10-11), it's a known bug but not corrected.

My program is not a web client and I would like to perform this conversion directly in VB6, severals programs manage to convert SVG to PNG, it is so complex to perform this conversion?

Comment: Maybe rendering the SVG inside a webbrowser control, then capturing the image?

Comment: Without JAVA or weird solution please !!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the following example. It loads an .svg file from your computer into canvas then converts it to .png using FileReader and dataURL.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Convert SVG to Canvas to PNG dataURL</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='padding:10px;font-family:arial'>
<center>
<h4>Convert SVG to Canvas to PNG dataURL</h4>
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
This is a utility used to convert files on your computer from SVG to a PNG dataURL

<br /><i>NOTE; This works in FF/CH. IE throws a security error</i>
</div>

<table><tr>


<td>
<div id=drawImgDiv>
</div>
<center>1.) canvas drawImage (svg)</center>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<canvas id=myCanvas></canvas>
</div>
<center>2.) Canvas</center>
</td>
<td>
<img id=pngImg  />
<center>3.) PNG</center>
</td>
<tr><td colspan=3 align=center>
<input title="file to DataURL" onChange=loadSVGFile() type="file" id="ImgFile" />
</td></tr>
</tr></table>

   <br />PNG dataURL: width="<span id=imgWidthSpan></span>"  height="<span id=imgHeightSpan></span>"      <br />
<textarea id=pngDataURLValue style='font-size:110%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:200px'></textarea>
  <br />
  <br />Javascript:<br />
<textarea id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
</center>

<script id=myScript>
var Reader = new FileReader();
//---file onChange---
function loadSVGFile()
{
 drawImgDiv.innerHTML=""

 var imgFile = ImgFile.files[0]; // ---FileList objec
 //--Only process image files---
 if (imgFile.type.match('image.*'))
 {
  //---Closure to capture the file information---
  Reader.onload = (function(theFile)
  {
  return function(e)
  {
   drawImgDiv.innerHTML += ['<img id=drawImage src="', e.target.result,
   '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
   drawImage.onload = function()
   {
    myCanvas.width=drawImage.width
    myCanvas.height=drawImage.height
    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext( "2d" );
    ctx.drawImage(drawImage, 0, 0 );
    var canvasdata = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    pngImg.src = canvasdata
    pngDataURLValue.value=canvasdata
    imgWidthSpan.innerHTML=drawImage.width
    imgHeightSpan.innerHTML=drawImage.height
   }
  };
  })(imgFile);

 //---Read in the image file as a data URL---
 Reader.readAsDataURL(imgFile);
 }
}

</script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
function init()
{

 jsValue.value=myScript.text
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I use the same code in thin client and it doesn't work in IE11 and unfortunately web browser in VB6 use IE engine, that's why I'm looking for another solution to perform this